# Would it make sense to say お好きに僕に連絡かけてください?

Tags: word-choice, syntax

Does お好きに僕に連絡かけてください sound natural, and does it make sense as a sentence? If not, what would a more natural alternative be? In particular, I'm unsure about お好きに and ください in the same sentence.

Comment: What are you trying to say? Why do you think it means that?

Comment: That and context, please.

Comment: お気軽にご連絡ください would be better if you want to say feel free to contact me. But this is business-like expression. If you want to say to your friends, 気軽に連絡してね is better.

Comment: You are looking for 気軽に、適当に、都合の良いタイミングで等。

Comment: Do you mean "at your disposal" by  お好きに? Then I think user51966 and oldergod gave good candidates.

Comment: I think we need much more clarity on the purpose of the お好きに. My guess is that the correct construction is 語遠慮せずに but I could be completely off as to what @sqrtbottle wants to do with the first part.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but I think you're trying to say something like

> Please feel free to contact me again.

Maybe? From your choice of 僕, I'm guessing this is not necessarily an overly formal context.

1. お好きに is not used like that. (Did you get this from お好きにどうぞ?) Depending on context and tone, もしよかったら or お気軽に or いつでも might be usable, although I don't know why you need it here in the first place. It's not like また連絡してくださいね would be interpreted as an obligation. (That would be お返事お待ちしております。よろしくお願いします。)
2. 僕に is superfluous, especially with 連絡**する** (see below). Who else are they going to contact?
3. Not <s>連絡かける</s>. It's 電話をかける and 連絡**する**.

Without context this is obviously a shot in the dark, but...

> いつでも連絡(して)ください

Answer (score 1):

I think that "お好きな**時**に連絡ください" also sounds natural.